# using a for loop to add columns to a data frame

Tags: r

I am new to R and it seems like this shouldn't be a difficult task but I cannot seem to find the answer I am looking for. I am trying to add multiple vectors to a data frame using a for loop. This is what I have so far and it works as far as adding the correct columns but the variable names are not right. I was able to fix them by using rename.vars but was wondering if there was a way without doing that.

```
for (i in 1:5) {
    if (i==1) {
    alldata<-data.frame(IA, rand1) }
    else {
    alldata<-data.frame(alldata, rand[[i]]) }
}
```

Instead of the variable names being rand2, rand3, rand4, rand5, they show up as rand..i.., rand..i...1, rand..i...2, and rand..i...3.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating your variables in a loop, you can assign the names during the loop

```
alldata <- data.frame(IA)
for (i in 1:5) {alldata[, paste0('rand', i)] <- rand[[i]]}
```

However, R is really slow at loops, so if you are trying to do this with tens of thousands of columns, the `cbind` and rename approach will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can set variable names using the `colnames` function. Therefore, your code would look something like:

```
newdat <- cbind(IA, rand1, rand[2:5])
colnames(newdat) <- c(colnames(IA), paste0("rand", 1:5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `cbind(IA, rand1, rand[2:5])`.

Comment: I tried this and the variable names are still not what I want them to be. For example, the rand2 name is "c(0.769488322349677, 1.02808554936668, 1.07762946633772, 1.1976398531684," which are the first 4 values of the variable.

Comment: Not rand2, `rand[2]`. Why would you expect the name to be `rand2`? The object name is `rand`, and you are asking for the second element in `rand`. Did you name that second element?